# Making links in ascending order for an excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

How do I make the links go up in ascending order in my excel file.

I am trying to do this with the simple auto feature feature and with formulas.

E.g:

```
https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues?page=3&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen
https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues?page=4&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen
https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues?page=5&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen
```

[Image](https://ibb.co/iDqM2w)

I cannot find an easy way to do this as auto feature does not work.  I have looked at a number of posts but none of them seem to be what I am after.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A quick google search gave me [this](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3113-excel-increment-number-with-text.html) which gives tip on incrementing in strings.

Comment: can you not use concantenation with ROWS() and a numric adjustment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using formulas on the worksheet, you can increment a number by filling down with the ROW() worksheet function and concatenate that into the string. To convert it to an active hyperlink, use the [HYPERLINK worksheet function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) as a 'wrapper'.

```
=HYPERLINK("https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues?page="&ROW(3:3)&"&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen")
```

In VBA the same can be accomplished in a loop.

```
Dim h As Long, addr As String

With Worksheets("sheet1")
    'fill A1:A5 with progressive hyperlinked pages
    For h = 3 To 7
        addr = "https://github.com/jakubroztocil/httpie/issues?page=" & h & "&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen"
        .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Cells(h - 2, "A"), Address:=addr, TextToDisplay:=addr
    Next h
End With
```